# Modeling Choices from Static List of Values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, pg-search

I have a model which may be associated with zero or more static values. For example, movies and genres (horror, action, etc.) I want to make an `genres` array on my model but I'm not sure the best way to reflect this in the database.

I am using Rails/AR 4 and Postgres along with the `pg_search` gem.

I can go the classic route of creating a `genres` table and creating a join table between the two. However, this seems a little bit like overkill because `genres` do not change very often.

I could create a `genre` enum type and then create an array of `genre`s on the the model but I'm not sure how well Active Record supports this sort of mechanism.

I will need to be able to search for movies based on genre as well as other criteria (keyword, length, rating, etc.)

Any best practices and/or resources would be greatly appreciated. Am I missing a simpler or more straight forward solution? Do any of the above fail to solve my problem in a way I am not anticipating?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend going with an other table rather than arrays.

Arrays are fine if you want to have free text. Here, you really want to have resource. If you have a "scifi" genre and, after realizing nobody understands what scifi is, decide to rename it to "scifi / fantastic", you now have to iterate on all your movies and check if the scifi name was used.

With a foreign table, that's easy. Your movie has a genre_id column, and your genre row has a name column that you can change to change all movies.

A good use of an array would be to describe detailed and adhoc attributes of the film, like atmosphere traits, innovative specificities, and anything that is a list of thing that would probably not be used for several movies and should be redacted enough.

Also note postgres array support [is not perfect](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/11159) in rails, as for now, and you may have to deal with a few glitches.